# Android Retrofit - Putting the response into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-mvvm

Hey guys I have retrofit successfully getting data from a rest API and its printing into the log. However when I try and capture this response into an array list I'm getting an error stating : "Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor). This error shows in the array list brackets <>

```
// Executes the network request on a background thread
        try {
            Response response = getWeather(locationCode, apiKey).execute();
            if (cancelRequest) {
                return;
            }
            if (response.code() == 200) {

                //  Weather weather = response.body().getWeather();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());

                List<Weather> list = new ArrayList<>(((Weather)response.body()));
                //mWeather.postValue(response);
```

GSON Response

```
 {
"coord": {
    "lon": -5.93,
    "lat": 54.58
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 804,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "overcast clouds",
        "icon": "04d"
    }
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 291.56,
    "feels_like": 286.36,
    "temp_min": 291.15,
    "temp_max": 292.15,
    "pressure": 1024,
    "humidity": 45
},
```

If anyone could help me root cause this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you added gson converter with retrofit like as follow?
addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

Comment: Yeah the gson parses fine, I can see it in the log. Its storing it in the arraylist thats causing me trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the POJO Class which you have created might not be proper as you have not shared your POJO class please try the below POJO class in your code an see if the error still persists.

```
public class Weather {

private coordinate coord;
private ArrayList<weatherinfo> weather;
private String base;
private maininfo main;

public coordinate getCoord() {
    return coord;
}

public ArrayList<weatherinfo> getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

public String getBase() {
    return base;
}

public maininfo getMain() {
    return main;
}

public static class coordinate{
    String lon,lat;

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
}

public static class weatherinfo{
    String id,main,description,icon;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}

public static class maininfo{
    String temp,feels_like,temp_min,temp_max,pressure,humidity;

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public String getFeels_like() {
        return feels_like;
    }

    public String getTemp_min() {
        return temp_min;
    }

    public String getTemp_max() {
        return temp_max;
    }

    public String getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public String getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }
}
}
```

After that while reading your response try it this way.

```
ArrayList<Weather.weatherinfo> list = response.body().getWeather();
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the pojo class works and returns the data into the log np. The ArrayList syntax you recommended doesnt work unfortunately. But thank you for tyring to help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the response to a usable java object, you will have to use Gson or use Retrofit to do it automatically. Since you are getting the generic `Response` from the call, it means you will have to do it yourself. So first convert the json schema to a POJO then instead of

```
List<Weather> list = new ArrayList<>(((Weather)response.body()));
```

use

```
ResponsePojo responsePojo = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), ResponsePojo.class);
```

However, instead of doing it manually, you should set up Retrofit correctly so that it does the conversion for you. Then you will get back your object directly from the retrofit call -

```
Response<ResponsePojo> response = getWeather(locationCode, apiKey).execute();
ResponsePojo responsePojo = response.body()
```